# Python: List or float or array to float

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a function which needs input as type `float` for further calculation. 
Unfortunately the input type ranges from:

1. `list`
2. `float`
3. `numpy.array`

I am unhappy with my workaround and I wonder whether there is a better solution.

```
def get_correct_float(x):
    try:
        if len(x) == 1:
            return x[0]
    except:
        return x      

a = [.5]
b = .5
c = np.array([.5])

get_correct_float(a) == get_correct_float(b) == get_correct_float(c)
TRUE
get_correct_float(a)
0.5
```

Comment: just do `float(np.asarray(x))`

Comment: `get_correct_float([1,2]) -> None` is that intended?

Comment: The input can only contain one single element - therefore this can not happen (in my case). But no, it is not intended.

Comment: Alright, it seems, asimoneau gave the right solution already. Thanks.

Comment: I have a follow-up question which is similiar yet not equal. Should i post a new question or simply modify my question also contain the other problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance),

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [[.5], .5, np.array([.5])] 
>>> f = [x if isinstance(x, float) else x[0] for x in l]
>>> f
[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

---

```
def get_correct_float(x):
    return x if isinstance(x, float) else x[0]
```

---

Previous answer,

```
import numpy as np

def get_correct_float(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return x[0]
    elif isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        return x[0]
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: I liked your original `if ... elif` version

Comment: Sure, I liked that it can be used more generally than this specific instance :).  It's easy to see how you would adapt it to other types/conversions.